# How to debug a user defined function

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, user-defined-functions

The user defined function below is causing duplicates and this causing a build to fail. What is the best approach to test each part of the function so I can pinpoint where the issue is? And assistance would be a huge benefit.

I've never really had to debug a function before as I assume you would run the code as select first before inserting into a user defined function.

```
USE [HealthBI]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_INS_CDSGetCommissionerCode]    Script Date: 03/10/2017 09:04:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*____________________________________________________________________________________
**  Procedure Name  : udf_INS_CDSGetCommissionerCode
**
**  Description     : Returns the comissioner code calculated via standard rules.
**  
**  Parameters      : 
**
**  Returns         : Commissioner Code (Varchar50)
**
**  Created by      : Insource  
**
**  Changes         : Date      : Vers  : By        : Comments
**                  _____________________________________________________________________________
**                  30/01/2012  : 1.00  : PJS       : Initial Design 
**                  20/06/2017  : 2.00  : JH        : UPDATE TO MEET COMMISSIONER DEFINITIONS 
**_______________________________________________________________________________________________
*/
CREATE function [dbo].[udf_INS_CDSGetCommissionerCode] (
 @CDS_TYPE as varchar(50), --'A&E','OPS','APC'
 @HospitalProviderSpellNumber as  VARCHAR(50),
 @OverseasVisitorStatusClassification AS VARCHAR(50),
 @AdministrativeCategoryCode AS VARCHAR(50),
 @PostcodeatEventDate AS VARCHAR(50),
 @ISPBR AS VARCHAR(50), 
 @GPatEventDate AS VARCHAR(50),
 @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider AS VARCHAR(50),
 @SourceofAdmissionHospitalProviderSpell AS VARCHAR(50),
 @ResponsibleCCG AS VARCHAR(50),
 @NHS_Service_Agreement_Line_Number AS VARCHAR(50), --USED AS A CHECK FOR CLOUMN B/C OF CROSS BORDER TABLE. PROBABLY REPLACE WITH A FLAG AT P4
 @Specialised_Level AS VARCHAR(50), --"0"/NULL not specialised, "1" Specialised, "2" Highly specialised     --SHOULD COME FROM                                                                                  -- load in appendix b for ref
 @IS_WITH_CROSS_BOARDER_AGREEMENT AS VARCHAR(50), --load in appendix H, add flag to ods psudo postcode table. IS_WITH_CROSS_BOARDER_AGREEMENT
 @POSTCODE_COUNTRY AS VARCHAR(50), --MANY CHECKS ARE MADE FOR THE COUNTRY OF THE POSTCODE, IT'S EASIER TO JUST HAVE THIS VALUE ON THE TABLE
 @GP_National_Grouping AS VARCHAR(50),
 @IS_Secondary_Dental_Care AS VARCHAR(50), --Codes can change, probably better to add a flag that can be updated in P4 (Also allows for CBRs for interim updates pending standard changes)
 @IS_Infertility_treatment AS VARCHAR(50), --Codes can change, probably better to add a flag that can be updated in P4 (Also allows for CBRs for interim updates pending standard changes)
 @GPStatusCode AS VARCHAR(50), --possibly a lookup instead
 @EpisodeNumber AS VARCHAR(50)
    )


    RETURNS varchar(50)

AS 

    BEGIN

        /*_______________________________________________________________________
        **Declare Local variables
        **________________________________________________________________________
        */
        DECLARE @CommissionerCode   as varchar(50)
        SET     @CommissionerCode   = NULL

        /*_______________________________________________________________________
        **Set code not mapped to null for some variables
        **________________________________________________________________________
        */
        SET @OverseasVisitorStatusClassification = ISNULL(NULLIF(@OverseasVisitorStatusClassification,'CODE NOT MAPPED'),'')
        SET @SourceofAdmissionHospitalProviderSpell = ISNULL(NULLIF(@SourceofAdmissionHospitalProviderSpell,'CODE NOT MAPPED'),'')
        SET @AdministrativeCategoryCode = ISNULL(NULLIF(@AdministrativeCategoryCode,'CODE NOT MAPPED'),'')
        SET @GPatEventDate = ISNULL(NULLIF(@GPatEventDate,'CODE NOT MAPPED'),'')
        SET @PostcodeatEventDate = ISNULL(NULLIF(@PostcodeatEventDate,'CODE NOT MAPPED'),'')
        SET @ISPBR = ISNULL(NULLIF(@ISPBR,''),'Y')
        /*_______________________________________________________________________
        **Process the calculation
        **________________________________________________________________________
        */


/*CHECK CDS TYPE
*/
If @CDS_TYPE = 'A&E' --Checks if the CDS type is A&E
GOTO Box_AE_1
ELSE 
GOTO Box_A


Box_AE_1:
/*Usual Place of Residence is in England A&E-1 
 TRUE if on the A&E Arrival Date: Postcode of Usual Address has a Country value of ‘E92000001’ in the ONS NHS Postcode Directory
*/

    IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'ENGLAND'
    GOTO Box_J
    ELSE
    Set @CommissionerCode = (select CCG_CODE from CDI_ODS_ALL_TRUST (NOLOCK) WHERE ORGANISATION_CODE = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)
    GOTO Box_Final

Box_A:
/*Patient Liable for Charges (Box A)
TRUE if any episode (in the PbR Spell) has: Overseas Visitor Status Classification = ‘4’ OR Administrative Category Code (On Admission) = ’02’ (Note episodes with this value are excluded from PbR Spells, so will not be found) CONSIDER ADDING: OR Organisation Code (Code of Commissioner) starts with “VPP”
*/ --WE DON'T HOLD OVERSEAS STATUS PER EPISODE.
        IF @OverseasVisitorStatusClassification = '4' or @AdministrativeCategoryCode = '02' 
        BEGIN
        set @CommissionerCode = 'VPP00'  --@GPatEventDate??
        GOTO Box_Final 
        END
        ELSE
        GOTO Box_B

Box_B: 
/*Ordinarily Resident in UK B 
FALSE if any episode (in the PbR Spell) has: Overseas Visitor Status Classification IN (‘’1, ‘2’, ’3’, ‘4’) 

FALSE if all episodes (in the PbR Spell) have: Overseas Visitor Status Classification NOT IN (‘’1, ‘2’, ’3’, ‘4’) AND in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): Postcode of Usual Address in form ‘BF1nAA’  

TRUE if in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): Postcode of Usual Address has a Country value of ‘E92000001’ OR ‘ ‘N92000002’ OR ‘S92000003’ OR ‘W92000004’ in the ONS NHS Postcode Directory
 */ 
    IF @OverseasVisitorStatusClassification IN ('1','2','3','4') or @PostcodeatEventDate LIKE 'BF1%'--Could replace this with a flag IS_UK_RESIDENT calculated at P4, probably better to us this field as it's used for other steps.
    GOTO Box_B_1
    ELSE
    GOTO Box_XB_1


Box_B_1:  
/*Highly Specialised Care B-1 
TRUE if: Derived PSS Code (PbR Spell level) is in the list of Highly Specialised Service Line Codes
 */
    IF @ISPBR = 'N'
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(IS_SCG_ACTIVITY,''),'N') FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE (NOLOCK)  WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber) ='Y'
            BEGIN
            GOTO Box_B_2
            END
            ELSE
            GOTO Box_B_3
        END
        ELSE
        IF @Specialised_Level = '2' --posibly do this check on feed to this fn
        GOTO Box_B_2
        ELSE
        GOTO Box_B_3

Box_B_2:  
/*Patient Resident in EU State with Cross Border Right of Access B-2 
TRUE if in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): Postcode of Usual Address is in the Cross Border Rights List
 */
    IF @IS_WITH_CROSS_BOARDER_AGREEMENT = 'Y'
    BEGIN
    SET @CommissionerCode = (select Footprint_Code from IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs (NOLOCK)  where IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs.Provider_Code = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)--'Lookup Organisation Code (Code of Provider) in the list of Contracted Providers for Specialised Services.  Use the related footprint code. ' --OUTPUT: S4, appendix b
    GOTO BOX_Final
    END
    ELSE
    GOTO BOX_B_3

Box_B_3: 
/*Overseas Visitor Charging Exemption B-3 
Unless guidance becomes clearer this will not be assessed in SUS+. Note: No incoming data fields will have been changed, so inferences can still be made from them.  CHECK GIBRALTER
*/ 
    --not defined in draft
    GOTO Box_B_4

Box_B_4: 
/*Usual Place of Residence is in England B-4 
TRUE if in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): General Medical Practice Code (Patient Registration) (GP Code) NOT IN ‘V81999’, ’V81998’, ’V81997’ AND The National Grouping for the GP Code is NOT ‘W00’ AND The National Grouping for the GP Code is NOT blank AND  The Status Code for the GP Code is ‘A’ or ‘P’ on the CDS Assignment Date (see section 5 of the source document – e.g. Use the Discharge Date for APC spells)

--THIS READS AS AN "OR" STATEMENT, AS IN, IF ANY OF THE CONDITIONS ARE MET. TBC
 */
    IF @GPatEventDate in ('V81999','V81998','V81997') or Left(@GP_National_Grouping,3) = 'W00' or @GPStatusCode in ('A','P') --COULD BE REPLACED BY A P4 CALCULATION
    BEGIN
    SET @CommissionerCode = (select CCG_CODE from CDI_ODS_ALL_TRUST (NOLOCK)  WHERE ORGANISATION_CODE = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider) --OUTPUT: S2 HOST
    GOTO Box_Final
    END
    ELSE
    SET @CommissionerCode = @ResponsibleCCG  --OUTPUT: S3 RESPONSIBLE
    GOTO Box_Final

Box_XB_1:
/*Live in Wales and Registered with an English GP XB-1 
TRUE if: Live in Wales (Next box) AND Registered with an English GP (Next but one box)
 */
     IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'WALES' AND @GP_National_Grouping like 'E%' --UPDATE THESE ONCE ONS DATA IS UPDATED.
     BEGIN
     GOTO BOX_C_0
     END
     ELSE 
     GOTO BOX_XB_2

Box_XB_2:
/*Usual Place of Residence in NI, Scotland or Wales XB-2 
TRUE if in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): Postcode of Usual Address has a Country value of ‘N92000002’ OR ‘S92000003’ OR ‘W92000004’ in the ONS NHS Postcode Directory
 */
     IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'SCOTLAND' OR @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'NI' OR @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'WALES'  --UPDATE THESE ONCE ONS DATA IS UPDATED.
     BEGIN
     GOTO BOX_C
     END
     ELSE 
     GOTO BOX_C_0


Box_C:
/*Is the activity specialised or highly specialised C and C-0 
For APC SUS+ will derive Prescribed Specialised Service Codes (PSS) and National Programme of Care (NPOC) at episode, whole spell and PbR spell level. Appropriate PSS and NPOC codes will be added to each OP record. The PbR Spell level PSS code, or OP record level PSS code, will be used to determine whether the spell/record qualifies as specialised or highly specialised.  Appropriate uplift to spell prices will be carried out. TRUE if the derived PSS Code is in the list of specialised or highly specialised codes 

Yet to be detailed: Additional derived commissioner codes where unbundled chemotherapy, unbundled radiotherapy, or neonatal critical care is found. Grateful for any help/advice.
 */
     IF @ISPBR = 'N'
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(IS_SCG_ACTIVITY,''),'N') FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE (NOLOCK)  WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber) ='Y'
            BEGIN
            GOTO BOX_C_1
            END
            ELSE
            SET @CommissionerCode = (select CLINICAL_COMMISSIONING_GROUP_CODE from CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY  (NOLOCK) WHERE POSTCODE = @PostcodeatEventDate) 
            GOTO BOX_Final
        END
        ELSE
        IF @Specialised_Level > 0 --UPDATE THESE ONCE ONS DATA IS UPDATED.
            BEGIN
            GOTO BOX_C_1
            END
            ELSE
            SET @CommissionerCode = (select CLINICAL_COMMISSIONING_GROUP_CODE from CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY  (NOLOCK) WHERE POSTCODE = @PostcodeatEventDate) 
            GOTO BOX_Final

Box_C_0:
/*Is the activity specialised or highly specialised C and C-0 
For APC SUS+ will derive Prescribed Specialised Service Codes (PSS) and National Programme of Care (NPOC) at episode, whole spell and PbR spell level. Appropriate PSS and NPOC codes will be added to each OP record. The PbR Spell level PSS code, or OP record level PSS code, will be used to determine whether the spell/record qualifies as specialised or highly specialised.  Appropriate uplift to spell prices will be carried out. TRUE if the derived PSS Code is in the list of specialised or highly specialised codes 

Yet to be detailed: Additional derived commissioner codes where unbundled chemotherapy, unbundled radiotherapy, or neonatal critical care is found. Grateful for any help/advice.
 */
      IF @ISPBR = 'N'
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(IS_SCG_ACTIVITY,''),'N') FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE (NOLOCK)  WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber) ='Y'
            BEGIN
            GOTO BOX_C_2
            END
            ELSE 
            GOTO BOX_D
        END
        ELSE
        IF @Specialised_Level > 0 --UPDATE THESE ONCE ONS DATA IS UPDATED.
            BEGIN
            GOTO BOX_C_2
            END
            ELSE
            GOTO BOX_D


Box_C_1:
/*Highly Specialised Service C-1 
TRUE if in any episode in the PbR spell: NHS Service Agreement Line Number is in Column B or C of Cross Border Flows for Specialised Services Decision needed.  Do we rely on incoming data or use the derived PSS codes – see previous box.  The derived code is at spell level not episode level.
 */
     IF @ISPBR = 'N'
     BEGIN
        SET @NHS_Service_Agreement_Line_Number = (SELECT SCG_SERVICE_LINE FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE (NOLOCK)  WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber)
        IF @NHS_Service_Agreement_Line_Number IN (SELECT Service_Line FROM IHealthBIConfig_SpecialisedServicesCrossborderFlows (NOLOCK) ) --USED AS A CHECK FOR CLOUMN B/C OF CROSS BORDER TABLE. PROBABLY REPLACE WITH A FLAG AT P4
        BEGIN
            SET @CommissionerCode = (SELECT Footprint_Code 
                                     FROM IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs  (NOLOCK) 
                                     WHERE IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs.Provider_Code = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)
            GOTO BOX_Final
        END
        ELSE 
        IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY ='scotland' --CONFIRM THIS CHECK
            BEGIN
            SET @CommissionerCode = 'SD002' --OUTPUT: S5
            GOTO BOX_Final
            END
            ELSE 
                IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'WALES'--CONFIRM THIS CHECK
                    BEGIN
                    SET @CommissionerCode = '7A5HC' --OUTPUT: S5
                    GOTO BOX_Final
                    END
     END
     ELSE
     IF @NHS_Service_Agreement_Line_Number IN (SELECT Service_Line FROM IHealthBIConfig_SpecialisedServicesCrossborderFlows (NOLOCK) ) --USED AS A CHECK FOR CLOUMN B/C OF CROSS BORDER TABLE. PROBABLY REPLACE WITH A FLAG AT P4
        BEGIN
        SET @CommissionerCode = (SELECT Footprint_Code 
                                 FROM IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs  (NOLOCK) 
                                 WHERE IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs.Provider_Code = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)
        GOTO BOX_Final
        END
        ELSE 
        IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY ='scotland' --CONFIRM THIS CHECK
            BEGIN
            SET @CommissionerCode = 'SD002' --OUTPUT: S5
            GOTO BOX_Final
            END
            ELSE 
                IF @POSTCODE_COUNTRY = 'WALES'--CONFIRM THIS CHECK
                    BEGIN
                    SET @CommissionerCode = '7A5HC' --OUTPUT: S5
                    GOTO BOX_Final
                    END

Box_C_2:
/*Does NHSE have a contract with the specialised service provider C-2 
TRUE if: Organisation Code (Code of Provider) is in a list of Contracted Providers for Specialised Services (Any episode because Organisation Code (Code of Provider) is the same on all episodes in a spell. 
 */
     IF @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider IN (SELECT Provider_Code FROM IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs) --APPENDIX J.
     BEGIN
     SET @CommissionerCode = (SELECT Footprint_Code 
                              FROM IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs  (NOLOCK) 
                              WHERE IHealthBIConfig_SpecialistServicesProvidersSpecialisedCommissioningHubs.Provider_Code = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)
     GOTO Box_Final
     END
     ELSE 
     SET @CommissionerCode = @ResponsibleCCG  --OUTPUT: S3
     GOTO Box_Final


Box_D:
/*Is the activity for secondary dental care? D 
TRUE if on any episode in the PbR spell the: Activity Treatment Function Code in in the list ‘140’, ‘141’, ‘142’, ‘143’, ‘144’, ‘217’, OR ‘450’
 */
     IF @ISPBR = 'N'
     BEGIN
          IF (SELECT 'Y' FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE  (NOLOCK) WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber AND CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE.TREATMENT_FUNCTION_CODE IN ('140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '217','450')) = 'Y'    
         BEGIN
            IF (ISNULL(@GPatEventDate,'') = '' OR @GPatEventDate in ('V81999','V81998','V81997'))
            BEGIN
                IF ISNULL(@PostcodeatEventDate,'') = ''
                    BEGIN
                    SET @CommissionerCode = (select NHS_AREA_TEAM_CODE from CDI_ODS_ALL_TRUST  (NOLOCK) JOIN CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY  (NOLOCK) on CDI_ODS_ALL_TRUST.POST_CODE = CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY.POSTCODE WHERE ORGANISATION_CODE = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)
                    GOTO BOX_Final
                    END
                ELSE
                SET @CommissionerCode = (select NHS_AREA_TEAM_CODE from CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY  (NOLOCK) WHERE CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY.POSTCODE = @PostcodeatEventDate)
                GOTO BOX_Final
            END
            ELSE
            SET @CommissionerCode = (SELECT HA_CODE FROM CDI_ODS_GENERAL_MEDICAL_PRACTICE (NOLOCK)  WHERE ORGANISATION_CODE = @GPatEventDate)
            GOTO BOX_Final 
         END
         ELSE 
         GOTO BOX_E
     END
     ELSE
         IF @IS_Secondary_Dental_Care = 'Y'  
         BEGIN
            IF (ISNULL(@GPatEventDate,'') = '' OR @GPatEventDate in ('V81999','V81998','V81997'))
            BEGIN
                IF ISNULL(@PostcodeatEventDate,'') = ''
                    BEGIN
                    SET @CommissionerCode = (select NHS_AREA_TEAM_CODE from CDI_ODS_ALL_TRUST (NOLOCK)  JOIN CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY (NOLOCK)  on CDI_ODS_ALL_TRUST.POST_CODE = CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY.POSTCODE WHERE ORGANISATION_CODE = @OrganisationCodeCodeofProvider)
                    GOTO BOX_Final
                    END
                ELSE
                SET @CommissionerCode = (select NHS_AREA_TEAM_CODE from CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY (NOLOCK)  WHERE CDI_ODS_ONS_NHS_POSTCODE_DIRECTORY.POSTCODE = @PostcodeatEventDate)
                GOTO BOX_Final
            END
            ELSE
            SET @CommissionerCode = (SELECT HA_CODE FROM CDI_ODS_GENERAL_MEDICAL_PRACTICE (NOLOCK)  WHERE ORGANISATION_CODE = @GPatEventDate)
            GOTO BOX_Final 
         END
         ELSE 
         GOTO BOX_E


Box_E:
/*Is the patient part of the eligible health and justice population? E 
For “APC” TRUE if on the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): Postcode of Usual Address is in the list of  Justice Addresses and Commissioners AND Source of Admission (Hospital Provider Spell) = ‘39’ 

For “OP” TRUE if on the Attendance date: Postcode of Usual Address is in the list of  Justice Addresses and Commissioners
 */
     IF @CDS_TYPE = 'OPS'
     BEGIN 
        IF @PostcodeatEventDate in (select Justice_Facility_Postcode from IHealthBIConfig_JusticeFacilityCode (NOLOCK) )
        BEGIN
        SET @CommissionerCode = (select NHS_England_Regional_Geography_with_Commissioning_Responsibility_Code from IHealthBIConfig_JusticeFacilityCode  (NOLOCK) where Justice_Facility_Postcode = @PostcodeatEventDate) 
        GOTO BOX_FINAL
        END
        ELSE GOTO BOX_F
     END
     ELSE
     IF @PostcodeatEventDate in (select Justice_Facility_Postcode from IHealthBIConfig_JusticeFacilityCode)
     AND @SourceofAdmissionHospitalProviderSpell = '39'
     BEGIN
     SET @CommissionerCode = (select NHS_England_Regional_Geography_with_Commissioning_Responsibility_Code from IHealthBIConfig_JusticeFacilityCode (NOLOCK)  where Justice_Facility_Postcode = @PostcodeatEventDate) 
     GOTO BOX_FINAL
     END
     ELSE GOTO BOX_F

Box_F:
/*Is the activity part of the agreed list of Public Health Section 7a services? 
Unless guidance becomes clearer this will not be assessed in SUS+.
 */
     --Is the activity part of the agreed list of Public Health Section 7a services? Unless guidance becomes clearer this will not be assessed in SUS+.

     GOTO BOX_H

Box_H:
/*Is it other Public Health activity? H  
Unless guidance becomes clearer this will not be assessed in SUS+
 */
     --Is it other Public Health activity?  Unless guidance becomes clearer this will not be assessed in SUS+.

     GOTO BOX_I

Box_I:
/*Is the activity for Infertility treatment? I 
TRUE if for any episode in the PbR Spell: Any ICD diagnosis code is in an infertility code list OR Any OPCS procedure code is in an infertility code list 
 */
     IF @ISPBR = 'N'
     BEGIN
        IF 'Y' = (SELECT DISTINCT [Y] FROM (
                    SELECT 'Y' [Y] FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE_DIAGNOSIS  (NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN [IHealthBIConfig_InfertilityDiagnosisProcedureCodes] (NOLOCK)  ON DIAGNOSIS = Code
                    WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber
                    UNION
                    SELECT 'Y' [Y] FROM CDI_APC_CONSULTANT_EPISODE_PROCEDURE (NOLOCK) 
                    INNER JOIN [IHealthBIConfig_InfertilityDiagnosisProcedureCodes]  (NOLOCK) ON [PROCEDURE] = Code
                    WHERE HOSPITAL_PROVIDER_SPELL_NUMBER = @HospitalProviderSpellNumber AND EPISODE_NUMBER = @EpisodeNumber)X)
        BEGIN
        GOTO BOX_I_1
        END
        ELSE 
        GOTO BOX_J
     END
     ELSE
     IF @IS_Infertility_treatment = 'Y' 
     BEGIN
        GOTO BOX_I_1
     END
     ELSE 
     GOTO BOX_J


/**********THESE LAST 2 STEPS BASICALLY CHECK IF THE RESPONSIBLE CCG IS 13Q THEN SET TO 13Q, OTHERWISE USE THE RESPONSIBLE CCG. WHICH IS THE SAME AS JUST USING THE CCG. LEFT THESE BOXES IN AS THIS IS BASED ON A DRAFT VERSION AND MAY CHANGE*****/
Box_I_1:
/*Does the activity meet NHSE eligibility for Armed Forces? I-1 
TRUE if in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): Organisation Code (Code of Commissioner) = ‘13Q’ 
 */
     IF @ResponsibleCCG = '13Q' --or  @PostcodeatEventDate LIKE 'BF1%' --GUIDANCE SAYS THAT IF THEY ARE ARMED FORCES
     BEGIN
     SET @CommissionerCode = '13Q' --OUTPUT: S12
     GOTO BOX_Final
     END
     ELSE 
     GOTO BOX_J --BASICALLY THE SAME CHECK?



Box_J:
/*DMS GP Practice Code Check J 
TRUE if in the first episode of the spell (whole spell) as at the Start Date (Hospital Provider Spell): General Medical Practice Code (Patient Registration) when checked against GP Practices in England and Wales has ‘13Q’ in the Commissioner column AND  The postcode column (in GP Practices in England and Wales) has a Country value of ‘E92000001’ when checked in the ONS NHS Postcode Directory 
 */
     IF @ResponsibleCCG = '13Q' AND @POSTCODE_COUNTRY ='ENGLAND'
     BEGIN
     SET @CommissionerCode = @ResponsibleCCG  --OUTPUT: S12
     GOTO BOX_Final
     END
     ELSE 
     SET @CommissionerCode = @ResponsibleCCG --OUTPUT: S3
     GOTO BOX_Final




        /*______________________________________________
        **return the result
        **______________________________________________*/
        Box_Final:
        RETURN @CommissionerCode

    END
GO
```

Comment: you can add print statements to see how it works

Comment: Thanks for posting the same [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0adb53ed-efdf-495a-89cb-82cda47ac256/whats-the-best-way-to-debug-a-user-defined-function?forum=transactsql) to multiple forums. Dan has the answer on msdn.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an answer for followers of this question.

@TheGameiswar comment: No, you cannot `print` statements from a UDF. You cannot even use `raiserror`.

What we can do:

1. One obvious way is to **extract the code** from UDF and test it in a separate solution, providing test inputs. However, I would assume anyone reading this thread already done that and it's not helping, because they need to test it in the context of another data. So the problem would only occur under some circumstances and cannot be reproduced by typical input.
2. @Lee's answer is kind of what I ended up doing last time. I ***copied*** my UDF into Stored Procedure, changed return part into logging and in place where the UDF is called, I *added* another line to execute SP next to the UDF. This way I got exactly the debug data I needed, within the complex structure of UDFs and SPs, with exactly the same context. When done with debugging, I just commented out the line where SP is executed. Very, very easy and powerful debugging.
3. Another good option, where possible, is to **pack the debug data into a return variable** (if it's table, especially if it has `Comment` like field) and handle it in parent SP.
4. **Stepping through debugger** is usually totally useless in my case, since my problem is usually buried within tons of UDFs and SPs and like two hundred thousands iterations deep.
5. One could also use `xp_cmdshell` to **output text to a text file**, which of course, would be stored on the server. This might require some server tweaking, though. Credits to @LDerckx's answer (I didn't test it):

   ```
   exec xp_cmdshell 'echo "mytextoutput" >> c:\debuginfo.txt'
   ```
6. Finally, you could **knowingly invoke an error** on the variable you're want to scope, even under some conditions (set within the UDF). It seems to me impractical, since you break the execution at each value you're scoping.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to rewrite a UDF as a stored proc to debug; you can also use the debugger in SQL Server (dev environment only) and step through the code.

Sidebar: long UDF with GOTOs I'd try and see if you could simplify the code.